# mysql - return all dogs from animal_type column

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know the right way to ask the question.

lets assume I have a table about animals.  Each row has information such as average weight, native climate, and animal_type.

I want to see all rows that are animal_type dogs,cats,fish

I have an array already created that lists each type, surrounded by ' and separated by a ,
code line:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ({$want_to_see}) = 'animal_type'";
```

gets parsed into

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ('dogs','cats','fish') = 'animal_type'
```

which yields

> Operand should contain 3 column(s)

on the output webpage.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: FYI: [When to use singlequotes, doublequotes, and backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, `animal_type` is a column.  If so, don't use single quotes.

And the function you want is [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE animal_type IN ({$want_to_see})";
```

Only use single quotes for string and date constants, never for column aliases.

Your specific error is a little inscrutable.  What is happening is that the a tuple of 3 strings is being compared to a single string.  That is why the error mentions 3 operands.

Comment: I made a slight edit to the answer adding a reference link, yet `IN()` is a function, not an operator.

Comment: the information about the quotation marks is very valuable.  thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that animal_type is the column name  you should use:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE animal_type in ('dogs','cats','fish');";
```

You should use the [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) function for an array of elements.

Comment: [*Same edit applies here...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441940/mysql-return-all-dogs-from-animal-type-column#comment68130887_40442001)

Comment: @Fred-ii-   many thanks  .especially for grammar errors  .. (for the set Theory in is an operator ... but for a lot of sql literature  is name as a function .. )

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE animal_type in ('dogs','cats','fish')
```

this should bring the desired results